# I can't access the wsdl of one of my bindings?

Tags: wcf

I have two endpoints: a basicHttp endpoint and a wsHttp endpoint. Each endpoint's base address is http://localhost:8181 which also happens to be the default for the basicHttp binding, so when I go to http://localhost:8181/ColorService.svc?wsdl, it see the wsdl.  For the wsHttp binding, I set a relative address of ws, so in the wsdl, it shows:

```
<soap12:address location="http://localhost:8181/ColorService.svc/ws/"/>
```

How do I access the wsdl for the above endpoint or is the wsdl just access through the base address meaning you don't access the wsdl different ways through different endpoint addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate WSDL for each endpoint. The WSDL will actually expose a separate `port` for each of your configured endpoints.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer.  It is all new to me.